# Numpy 2d array: account for border elements when modifying neighbouring elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I'm using CodeSignal exercises to learn programming, so here it goes. 
I have a 2d numpy array (called *matrix*) (doesn't have to be numpy though, if any better structure exists for this purpose), and 2 for loops which loop through each element in the matrix, checking if it meets some condition. 
I have created a np.zeros array of the same size as the input matrix (called *result*), which will be populated with my result.

Back to the for loops. When the condition is met for a given element with indices i,j of *matrix*, I want the programme to identify all the neighbouring elements and add a 1 to each of them.

So for example if

```
matrix = [[True, False, False], 
         [False, False, False], 
         [False, False, False]]
```

Then

```
result = [[0, 1, 0], 
          [1, 1, 0], 
          [0, 0, 0]]
```

What I have now:

```
matrix = np.array(matrix)            
(row, col) = matrix.shape
result = np.zeros((row,col), dtype=int)

for i in range(0, row): 
    for j in range(0, col):
        print(i,j)
        if matrix[i,j] == True:
             matrix[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2] += 1      ##problem 
return result
```

The problem with the line I have indicated is of course it does not work if the element is at a border, since there is no i-1 or i+2 etc.. (I tried, no error message, it just does not perform any function on the zeros matrix). 
I could write a bunch of if-statements like if i == 0 or j == 0 or i == row or j == col and specify separate slicing for each, but there must be a way easier method than that, which I can not think of or find.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: You should try whenever possible not to use `for` loops while working with `numpy` arrays and replace them with vectorised actions. Otherwise no `np` is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Add up sub-matrixes:

```
matrix = np.array(matrix)            
result = np.zeros(matrix.shape, dtype=int)
result[1:,1:] += matrix[:-1,:-1]
result[1:,:] += matrix[:-1,:]
result[1:,:-1] += matrix[:-1,1:]
result[:,1:] += matrix[:,:-1]
result[:,:-1] += matrix[:,1:]
result[:-1,1:] += matrix[1:,:-1]
result[:-1,:] += matrix[1:,:]
result[:-1,:-1] += matrix[1:,1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to convolve your matrix using kernel `[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]` and then replace initial cellswith zeros. Usual way is to use `scipy` for that like so:

```
>>> matrix = np.array([[True, False, False], 
                  [False, False, False], 
                  [False, False, False]])
>>> M = scipy.signal.convolve2d(matrix, 
           np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]), 
           mode='same')
>>> M
array([[1, 1, 0],
   [1, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]])
```

However `numpy` allows to perform 1D convolution only. But since our kernel is very symmetric, I have found a little hacky way how to achieve the same result as with 2D convolution:

```
M = np.vstack([np.convolve(n, [1, 1, 1], 'same') for n in matrix])
M = np.column_stack([np.convolve(n, [1, 1, 1], 'same') for n in matrix.T])
```

If you want to assign initial cells to zeroes, it's possible to do it like so:

```
np.logical_xor(M, matrix)
```

Comment: Btw, I have to break my `for` rule here because it's quite hard to use it in more difficult cases like this one.